# Sum of distinct items values Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

I got data like this:

```
ITEM    COLOR   VOL
1       RED     3
2       BLUE    3
3       RED     3
4       GREEN   12
5       BLUE    3
6       GREEN   12
```

and I want to have the total sum of each color, 
mean RED + BLUE + GREEN = 3+3+12 = 18

P.S I can't do it in sub-query since it is a part of a big query already. I am looking for a way could do it in select clause.something like

```
select sum(distinct(COLOR) VOL) from myTable group by COLOR
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `mean RED + BLUE + GREEN` ... does "mean" here mean (no pun intended) _average_, or something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen COLOR and VOL is constant

Comment: The query I gave you should work, but it leaves me wondering what is going on with your data.

Comment: Are you saying that in your data you may have many rows with color `RED`, but they will all have the same value for `VOL`? If so, is this stored in a base table, or is it the result of other queries? If it's the latter, say so, since perhaps the sum can be computed earlier in the process. If it's in a base table, why are your tables not in Second Normal Form? Why don't you have a separate, very small table just storing the `VOL` for each `COLOR`?

Comment: ... and I see your PS. If you don't want this in a subquery, but in your existing one, wouldn't you think that **seeing** your current query could help us give a good answer?

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for replying and you are right, it is result of other queries. Sorry for can't give a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum(max(vol)) from ... group by color
```

will work, but it's not clear why you should need such a thing. Likely this sum can be computed (much) earlier in your query, not right at the end.

Proof of concept (on a standard Oracle schema):

```
SQL> select sum(max(sal)) from scott.emp group by deptno;

SUM(MAX(SAL))
-------------
        10850

1 row selected.
```

Comment: Can aggregate functions be nested in Oracle?  I think in most RDBMS this would error out.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - do you have access to Oracle? You can test it yourself (for example on SCOTT.EMP). The answer is **yes**. I went ahead and added an example.

Answer (score 3):

One approach uses a CTE or subquery to find the mean volumes for each color.  Then take the sum of all mean volumes, for all colors.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT COLOR, AVG(VOL) AS VOL   -- or MIN(VOL), or MAX(VOL)
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY COLOR
)
SELECT SUM(t.VOL)
FROM cte t
```

Answer (score 3):

Sum the sum of distinct, as grouped by color

```
select sum(sum(distinct VOL))
from MyTable
group by COLOR
```

Tested locally and [here](http://rextester.com/GQTXAZ26637)

Comment: Hi John, it's kinky to mix distinct with group by.

Comment: return ORA-00937 :(

Comment: @BadLeo That would imply that something is not being grouped properly elsewhere...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I found a similar exmple on a recent Oracle training excercise

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not sure why you think it's "kinky"; you can absolutely run aggregate (and analytic) functions over distinct values - most commonly seen with `count(distinct <item>)`, but applicable to other functions. And I'd be surprised if this was just an Oracle thing. It would, of course, be very strange if the DISTINCT was outside of the function, but that was not the case with John's answer.

Comment: @Boneist I retract my comment, for some reason the query looked strange to me.  Well, it isn't nice to keep commenting, so I'll shutup now.  Upvoted +1